# import data from CSV file to a temporary table in API Platform

Tags: api-platform.com

I am looking to import csv file data to a temporary table or even any other ways of dealing with csv data import in API platform.

I do know in MySQL, we can import csv using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` query to a temporary table, validate and store data, in high speed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How does your scenario relate to API Platform? Do you need to access the data in this temporary table through api resources? If so, the generic answer to your question would likely involve implementing a [custom data provider](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/#data-providers) that knows how to access these temporary tables and is able to deserialize its data into the desired api resources.

Comment: @JeroenvanderLaan My main goal is to store large data into my API resource without calling in multiple times. For example, let' say I have 10,000 rows of data, I would have to call the post API 10,000 and this will trigger an error as It will take a long time to execute.

The best scenario will be doing something like MySQL `LOAD DATA` which is incredibly fast.

Also, I have no idea how to get raw query working in API platform handler or controller

Comment: You don't have to use the resource endpoints in order to insert data. If you already have an api resource implemented that correctly maps to your table(s), you can simply insert this data directly and API Platform will be able to work with it. This is quite a common thing to do.

Comment: @JeroenvanderLaan

hmm, maybe I am still not understanding you correctly.

I have my API resource set up with post endpoint, `/api/sale_codes`
with fields, `offer`, `code`.

Imagine this now, I will have 10,000 rows of data like

summer, dgd35436 | 
summer, dfdsfef343 | 
fall, fdfsfdfsd | 
...

You are saying could just make a post request to `/api/sale_codes` with 10000 rows od data and api-platform will handle it?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you can just import this data into your database directly, not using API Platform at all. Then implement an API resource (like `SaleCode`) that maps to this imported data so that you can use API Platform in order to interact with it.

Comment: @JeroenvanderLaan oops, misread your previous commet. Yes, you are right, a direct import to my db would definitely be the easier way. However, I cant do that cause the data is coming from react frontend and I am restricting all backend stuff handled through api platform endpoints

Comment: I will post an answer to your other question to help you import this csv data directly through API Platform (using Doctrine).

Comment: @JeroenvanderLaan Thank you so much, really appreciate it